# How to redirect from react web app to mobile app via deeplink

Tags: android, ios, reactjs

I have a deep link of a mobile app like mobileapp://dashboard. This app is using an iframe in order to connect to our web app that's written in react. When user clicks on a button in this react web app, I want to redirect the user from the web app, that's in iframe, to mobile app's certain screen by using that deep link which is dashboard. I tried a lot of things but couldn't do that. Can I handle that situation from just web app without touching mobile app's code because I can only work on web app.

I tried wrapping button with `<a href = 'mobileapp://dashboard'>`, putting window.location.href = 'mobileapp://dashboard' and navigate('mobileapp://dashboard') into onClick event but they didn't work.